# How do I add annotation information to ped file and run on PLINK?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, data-manipulation

My original `ped` file does not contain annotation information. Hence, I edited the first 6 columns of the original `ped` file by using the annotation info from `clinical_table.txt` and saved it as `subjects_153_edited.txt`.

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(data.table)
> subjects_153_ped <- read.table("subjects_153.ped")
> ann <- read.table("clinical_table.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
> subjects_edited <- ann %>% transmute(FID=Database_ID, IID=1, PAT=1, MAT=1, SEX=sex, PHENOTYPE=Profile) %>% mutate(SEX=recode(SEX,"M"="1","F"="2")) %>% left_join(subjects_153_ped, by=c("FID"="V1"))
> write.table(subjects_edited, "subjects_153_edited.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

Desired file formatting: PED file format https://plink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plink_fmt/ https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360035531972-PED-Pedigree-format

I then try to run `plink` to filter based on several conditions:

```
./plink –file subjects_153_edited.txt –map subjects_153.map --maf 0.1 --geno 0.1 --mind 0.3 --hwe 0.001 –recode –make-bed --out filtered
```

Traceback:

```
> Error: Half-missing call in .ped file at variant 1, line 1.
```

Data

```
> dput(ann[1:6,])
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15"), Collection_type = c("Array", "Array", "Array",
"Array", "Array", "Array"), Age = c(40L, 51L, 19L, 49L, 48L,
44L), Round_Age = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 45L), sex = c("M",
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), race = c("White", "White", "White",
"White", "White", "White"), Profile = c("Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "BP", "Unaffected control"), DSM_IV = c(295.9, 295.9, 295.9,
296.44, 296.7, NA), Axis_I_Primary_Dx = c("SCHIZ UNDIFF", "SCHIZ UNDIFF",
"SCHIZ UNDIFF", "BP I", "BP I", "CONTROL"), PMI = c(34L, 43L,
28L, 19L, 18L, 28L), Brain_PH = c(6.18, 6.63, 6.73, 5.87, 6.5,
6.59), Left_Brain = c("Fixed", "Frozen", "Frozen", "Fixed", "Frozen",
"Fixed"), Suicide_Status = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"
), Psychotic_Feature = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown",
"No"), Rate_Of_Death = c("Possible anoxia at death (e.g., CO poisoning or pneumonia)",
"Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden"), Exacerbation = c("No evidence of exacerbation",
"No evidence of exacerbation", "No evidence of exacerbation",
"Definite", "No evidence of exacerbation", "Unknown"), Smoking_At_TOD = c("Yes",
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown"), Lifetime_Alcohol_Use = c("Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Little or none (less than 1 drink/day)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)"
), Lifetime_Drug_Use = c("Moderate drug use in present", "Social",
"Heavy drug use in present", "Little or none", "Moderate drug use in present",
"Little or none"), Lifetime_Antipsychotics = c(75000L, 130000L,
2500L, 4000L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(subjects_153_ped[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(V1 = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14",
"AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1"), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V7 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
2L), V8 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V9 = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), V10 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(subjects_edited[1:16,1:16])
structure(list(FID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14",
"AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22",
"AC23", "AC24", "AC25"), IID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PAT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1), MAT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1), SEX = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1",
"2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1"), PHENOTYPE = c("Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz."
), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V7 = c(2L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V8 = c(2L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    V9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 2L), V10 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V11 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA,
16L), class = "data.frame")
```